# setIndeterminateDrawable() in onPostExecute using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i'm using a AsyncTask ProgressDialog to display some message. While processing it has an image instead of the spinning circle. I have set this in onPreExecute as :-

```
Drawable myIconStart = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagestart);
this.dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
this.dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(myIconStart); 
this.dialog.setMessage("Processing… please wait for confirmation");
```

Now when the work is done,  in onPostExecute , i'm setting as:-

```
Drawable myIconDone = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagedone);
            this.dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            this.dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(myIconDone);
            this.dialog.setMessage("Your Reservation has been confirmed");
```

But, the second image at onPostExecute is not being set. The First Image appears and then disappears, the second image appears as blank. Could you please tell me what i'm doing wrong/what i'm supposed to do?

Comment: The client requirement has changed, now i have to show a processing spinner first and on post execute i have to show the second image

Comment: due to time constraint, i just went ahead with laalto's suggestion. But still haven't understood why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the indeterminate drawable cannot really be replaced.

For your requirement, consider writing a custom dialog with a layout consisting of a `ProgressBar`, an `ImageView` for the done icon and a `TextView` for the message. Switch the visibility of the icon and progress bar when changing state.

Comment: hi laalto, would you happen to know, what could be the reason why the image doesn't appear onPostExecute?

Comment: Not really. Yesterday I spent some time debugging it but gave up and decided it's better to change the approach to a custom dialog if you need a similar result.